# Calling generic functions on rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bsxfun

I'd like to compute kernel matrices efficiently for generic kernel functions in
Matlab. This means I need to compute `k(x,y)` for every row `x` of `X`
and every row `y` of `Y`. Here is some matlab code that computes what I'd
like, but it is rather slow,

```
function K=compute_kernel( k_func, X, Y )
    m = size(X,1);
    n = size(Y,1);
    K = zeros(m,n);
    for i = 1:m
        for j = 1:n
            K(i,j) = k_func(X(i,:)', Y(j,:)');
        end
    end
end
```

Is there any other approach to this problem, e.g. some `bsxfun` variant that
calls a function on every row taken from `X` and `Y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdist2(X,Y, dist_func)` unfortunately computes `dist_func(X, Y(i,:))`, instead of `dist_func(X(i,:), Y(i,:))`. So the actual function I need is,

```
function K=compute_kernel( k_func, X, Y )
  % Woohoo! Efficient way to compute kernel
  size(X)
  size(Y)
  m = size(X,1);
  n = size(Y,1);
  for i = 1:n
    K(:,i) = pdist2( Y(i,:), X, k_func);
end
```

It's not as nice as just using `pdist2`, but is still much more efficient than the previous case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) with custom distance function?

P.S.
It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)